# Javascript: Object context overwritten?

Tags: javascript, json, oop

I understand there is some sort of context mix up in the following Javascript code I have.

Could someone explain my why I have this problem and how to solve the issue?

I have a class called Model which seems to work just fine. In this class is a method called update(). This will perform an AJAX call to the backend and parse the returned JSON. That's where things get tricky. The correct query is sent to the backend and the correct JSON is sent back. However, during parsing, there is some kind of collision or context issue between both models.

I call the update function through another object called View. This View object has a list of models (instances of Model). The view will then call each update function of each view. This works great until the returned data is parsed.

As mentioned in the comments, here's an example of the data object (recreated by hand, couldn't figure out how to copy it from the console). Note that this object may possibly not have all the entries in index 0 (in the following case it could be missing TLM_NO for example). In addition, the number of returned rows (in this case only '0' varies). Part of the goal of the update function is to detect this and fill in the correct parts of the DOM with 'N/A' in case there is nothing.

```
{valid: true,
 0: {'TLM_NO': '00000', 'TLM_NAME': 'YYY-14 Tlm Rel 19'}}
```

In the following code, everything is good until the line where there's the comment "/!\ HERE /!\".

```js
this.update = function(dbi) {
console.log('Updating model ' + this.name + '.');
var modelObj = this; // This is used to have a reference to 'this' Model while in other contexts.
if (this.columns.length == 0) {
    /* Let's build all the columns */
    $("[id^='" + this.ref + "']").each(function() {
    var colName = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
    if (modelObj.columns.indexOf(colName) == -1) {
        modelObj.columns.push(colName);
    }
    });
}

/* Let's build the bindings. */
var allBindings = {};
for (placeholder in this.bindings) {
    allBindings[placeholder] = this.bindings[placeholder].val();
}

$.post(path + 'inc/fetch.php', {
    dbi : dbi,
    table : this.table,
    columns : btoa(this.columns),
    limit : this.limit,
    offset : this.offset,
    distinct : this.distinct,
    where : btoa(this.where),
    bindings : btoa(JSON.stringify(allBindings))
}, function(data) {
    if (!data.valid) {
    $("#userError>p>span.userMessage").html(data.msg);
    $("#userError").dialog({
        width : 500,
        buttons : {
        'Dismiss' : function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
        }
    });
    } else {
    /* The data returned by the backend is simply JSON data with the key-value pair. There is one key per row returned. */
    var numRows = 0; // /!\ HERE /!\ Starting here, displaying the data variable will always display the first of two objects.
    for ( var rowID in data) {
        if (rowID == 'valid')
        continue;
        numRows++;
        for (column in data[rowID]) {
        console.log('[' + modelObj.str() + '] setting #' + modelObj.ref + '-' + column + ' to [' + data[rowID][column] + ']');
        var el = $('#' + modelObj.ref + '-' + column);
        var val = data[rowID][column];
        switch (el[0].nodeName) {
        case "SELECT":
            el.html('<option val="' + val + "'>" + val + "</option>");
            break;
        case "TD":
            el.text(val);
            break;
        case "INPUT":
            el.val(val);
            break;
        default:
            console.log('Dont know how to display "' + val + '"!');
        }
        }
    }
    if (numRows < modelObj.columns.length) {
        for ( var cNo in modelObj.columns) {
        var column = modelObj.columns[cNo];
        console.log("col = " + column);
        console.log('data');
        console.log(data);
        console.log('columns');
        console.log(modelObj.columns);
        console.log('[0] of ' + '#' + modelObj.ref)
        var par = $('#' + modelObj.ref).nodeName;
        var el = $('#' + modelObj.ref + '-' + column);
        var val = data[0][column];
        switch (par) {
        case "SELECT":
            el.html('<option val="' + val + "'>" + val + "</option>");
            break;
        case "TABLE":
            var limit = $('#' + modelObj.ref + ">tr").length - 1; // The first line (tr) is the header.
            for ( var missingRow in limit) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(missingRow) == 0 || data[missingRow].hasOwnProperty(column) == 0) {
                console.log('[' + modelObj.str() + '] setting #' + modelObj.ref + '-' + column + ' to [N/A]')
                $('#' + modelObj.ref + '-' + column + '-' + missingRow).text('N/A');
            }
            }

            break;
        case "INPUT":
            el.val(val);
            break;
        default:
            console.log('Dont know how to display "' + val + '"!');
        }

        }
    }
    }
}, "json");
};
```

Any thought is helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be quite handy if you provided an example data object.

Comment: Also, if 'for ( var rowID in data)' is used for parsing an array, the more foolproof way of doing so is using the traditional for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++). Or at least check whether rowId is what you think it is.

Comment: @Fenixp good idea. Added now.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more transparent to use a different structure, like so: http://pastebin.com/Bhz9rsVm ? I'm not sure how to help you with the code as it would require closer inspection that I don't quite have time to, but making the object clearer might just help alleviating the problem

Comment: A note: Your code is hard to read because it is not easy to see if the variables are already _bounded_ to the scope or if there is a scoping issue. While at first `for (column in data[rowID]) {` looked like `column` is not _bounded_ to the function scope,  at the second look is is clear that it is, because it is later defined with `var column = modelObj.columns[cNo];`. (JavaScript does not have block level scopes, it _just_ has function level scopes, and it does not matter where in the scope the `var variableName;` statement is written).

Comment: @Fenixp, yes that's a good idea. Let me implement that now.

Comment: @t.niese , thanks for pointing this out. The for loop you mentioned should have had its own "column" variable, so I just changed that. That said, the objects still seem to interfere. Do you have recommendations on how to make my code easier to read? I'm always looking for code improvements. Thanks.

Comment: To make it easier to read you should _define_ the variables at the beginning of the corresponding scope. e.g. `this.update = function(dbi) { var modelObj = this, allBindings; ...`, `function(data) { var numRows /*some comment about num Rows*/, rowID /*some comment about rowID */, el, val, cNo, column, par, limit, missingRow;` That way you can see right at the beginning which variables are bound to that scope. And it helps to keep in mind that JavaScript has no block level scopes and makes it easier to detect such issues and avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By declaring all the variables at the top of the scope I wanted them to be defined in, and by rearranging the returned JSON data in a more structured way (cf. paste below), I was able correct the issue.

For reference, here's the JSON data.

```
{"items":[{"TLM_NO":"0000000","TLM_NAME":"NSS-14 Tlm Rel 19"}],"valid":true}
```

Here's the updated `update` method.

```js
this.update = function(dbi) {
var modelObj = this/* This is used to have a reference to 'this' Model while in other contexts. */;
var allBindings = {} /* Used to relate binding to their values */;
console.log('Updating model ' + this.name + '.');
if (this.columns.length == 0) {
    /* Let's build all the columns */
    $("[id^='" + this.ref + "-']").each(function() {
    var colName = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
    if (modelObj.columns.indexOf(colName) == -1) {
        modelObj.columns.push(colName);
    }
    });
}

/* Let's build the bindings. */
for ( var placeholder in this.bindings) {
    allBindings[placeholder] = this.bindings[placeholder].val();
}

$.post(path + 'inc/fetch.php', {
    dbi : dbi,
    table : this.table,
    columns : btoa(this.columns),
    limit : this.limit,
    offset : this.offset,
    distinct : this.distinct,
    where : btoa(this.where),
    bindings : btoa(JSON.stringify(allBindings))
}, function(data) {
    var numRows = 0 /* Used to parse data. */;
    var el /* Will store the element where to set the */;
    var val /* will store the current value returned in JSON. */;
    var par /* will store the parent element of 'el'. */;
    var updateRows = true; /* This is used to count the rows. We only have to count them once. */
    if (!data.valid) {
    $("#userError>p>span.userMessage").html(data.msg);
    $("#userError").dialog({
        width : 500,
        buttons : {
        'Dismiss' : function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
        }
    });
    return;
    } else {
    /* The data returned by the backend is simply JSON data with the key-value pair. There is one key per row returned. */

    for ( var rowID in data.items) {
        for ( var cur_Column in data.items[rowID]) {
        if (updateRows)
            numRows++;

        console.log('[' + modelObj.str() + '] setting #' + modelObj.ref + '-' + cur_Column + ' to [' + data.items[rowID][cur_Column] + ']');
        el = $('#' + modelObj.ref + '-' + cur_Column);
        val = data.items[rowID][cur_Column];
        switch (el[0].nodeName) {
        case "SELECT":
            el.append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + "</option>");
            break;
        case "TD":
            el.text(val);
            break;
        case "INPUT":
            el.val(val);
            break;
        default:
            console.log('Dont know how to display "' + val + '"!');
        }
        }
        updateRows = false;
    }

    if (numRows < modelObj.columns.length) {
        for ( var cNo in modelObj.columns) {
        var curColumnCorr = modelObj.columns[cNo];
        par = $('#' + modelObj.ref)[0].nodeName; // TODO add model name to whatever parent there is.
        el = $('#' + modelObj.ref + '-' + curColumnCorr);
        switch (par) {
        case "TABLE":
            for ( var missingRow = 1; missingRow <= modelObj.limit; missingRow++) {
            if (data.items.hasOwnProperty(missingRow) == 0 || data.items[missingRow].hasOwnProperty(curColumnCorr) == 0) {
                console.log('[' + modelObj.str() + '] setting ' + '#' + modelObj.ref + '-' + curColumnCorr + '-' + missingRow + ' to [N/A]');
                $('#' + modelObj.ref + '-' + curColumnCorr + '-' + missingRow).text('N/A');
            } else {
                console.log(data.items);
            }
            }

            break;
        default:
            console.log('WARNING: Implementation of filling in values for a ' + par + ' parent is pending.');
        }
        }
    }
    }
}, "json");
};
```

Comment: Glade that you where able to solve your issue. An additional note, just to be sure that you understand the _anomaly_  of the `var` statement. While writing `for ( var rowID in data.items) {`  is valid, this could give the false impression that the scope of `rowID` is just with the loop. But as I already wrote, it does matter where you write a `var varName` statement in the function, as long as it exists. e.g. `for( i=0; i<10; i++) { ... } var i;` has the same effect as writing `var i; for( i=0; i<10; i++) { var i; ... }` or `for( var i=0; i<10; i++) { ... }`.